# Using conditional rules to describe past unreal events

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Recently I just had a flight to my village. My plane got into the Cumulonimbus cloud and got some heavy turbulences, but luckily we survived and arrived safely in my village.

I want to make a hypothetical sentence based on the past horrible moment like the following :

"I thought we would never survive. I cried **as if I would have never touched the earth again**".

Is that past unreal conditional sentence correct?

Comment: "I thought we would never survive. I cried, fearing we would never set foot on earth again."

Answer (score 1):

I feel that taking out the word "have" and removed the "ed" in touched would make this sentence work better.
Read both sentences aloud so you can hear the difference:
"I thought we would never survive. I cried **as if I would have never touched the earth again.**"
"I thought we would never survive. I cried **as if I would never touch the earth again.**"

I am sorry you went through this tragedy. I am glad you were fine, and I hope you never have to experience anything terrible like that again.
I am happy that you made it to your village. **<3**

Answer (score 0):

"as if I never would touch earth again."

Comment: I'm not sure that "as if" does it. You can certainly say "I cried as if I was in pain". But in this instance I believe a linking verb would greatly help matters e.g. "I cried thinking I would never....", "I cried imagining I would never...", "I cried supposing I would never..." etc.

Comment: @WS2 is correct that there are better ways to structure the sentence, but colloquially people would use "as if."  However, I'd reverse "never would" and, oddly, I'd keep the article.  I.E., "...as if I would never touch the the Earth again."  As with most things concerning the language, there are 101 ways to say something and 102 opinions as to which one is the best.